# Multiply a CvMat* and a number

Tags: opencv, matrix, computer-vision

I'm working with some filters in OpenCV and don't know how to multiply a number (1/5) in this example

```
CvMat* kernel=0; 

    IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize( entrada ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    kernel = cvCreateMat(3, 3,CV_32FC1);
    cvSet2D( kernel, 0, 0, cvRealScalar(1));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 0, 1, cvRealScalar(1));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 0, 2, cvRealScalar(1));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 1, 0, cvRealScalar(1));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 1, 1, cvRealScalar(2));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 1, 2, cvRealScalar(1));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 2, 0, cvRealScalar(1));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 2, 1, cvRealScalar(1));
    cvSet2D( kernel, 2, 2, cvRealScalar(1));

    // Matriz utilizada para el filtrado paso alto
    // 1 1 1
    // 1 2 1
    // 1 1 1

    cvFilter2D(entrada, dst, kernel, cvPoint(-1,-1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `cvScale(src, dst, scale)` with `scale` being the number, whatever matrix you want to multiply it with. If you want to multiply it with the kernel, what about just initializing the kernel with the multiplied values?